# How do I target $SNAP_DATA from snapcraft.yaml

Tags: snapcraft

Here are the important parts of my ***working*** `snapcraft.yaml`...

```
name: my-lib
apps:
  library-sample:
    command: library_sample $SNAP/arg_file.json

parts:
  library:
    source: https://github.com/the/sample.git
    plugin: cmake
    install: |
      cp -r samples/library_sample $SNAPCRAFT_PART_INSTALL/
      cp -r ../src/samples/src/arg_file.json $SNAPCRAFT_PART_INSTALL/
      cp --parents modules/dep_lib1/libdep_lib1.so $SNAPCRAFT_PART_INSTALL/
      cp --parents modules/dep_lib2/libdep_lib2.so $SNAPCRAFT_PART_INSTALL/
```

Ultimately, I would like `arg_file.json` to be in `$SNAP_DATA`, so I changed

`cp -r ../src/samples/src/arg_file.json $SNAPCRAFT_PART_INSTALL/`

to

`cp -r ../src/samples/src/arg_file.json $SNAP_DATA/`

However, this causes the file to disappear from my `install` directory (and ultimately from my installed snap). I feel certain this is because the `$SNAP_DATA` environment variable is not available to me from the `install:` scriptlet, but I don't know how I should work around this otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Snapcraft is a build-time tool. The `install` scriptlet you're using there runs *when the snap is being created*, not when the snap is installed.

`$SNAP_DATA` and its kind (`$SNAP_COMMON`, `$SNAP_USER_DATA`, etc.) are defined by snapd at *run-time*. In other words, there is no `$SNAP_DATA` defined when snapcraft is creating the snap.

If you want to place files into `$SNAP_DATA` when the snap is installed, you can do so by utilizing the [configure hook](https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/wiki/hooks#configure), which runs upon installation (for reference, [here](https://kyrofa.com/posts/snap-updates-automatic-rollbacks) is a tutorial of using the `configure` hook for health checks). However, since the `configure` hook runs *after* services start up, if you change your `app` to be a daemon this won't work (assuming your service needs files in `$SNAP_DATA` before it'll start up).

Another option that would work in that case would be to create shell script wrappers for your binaries and/or services to copy necessary files over to `$SNAP_DATA` before running the real commands. [Here](https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap/blob/master/src/apache/scripts/run-httpd) is an example wrapper for Apache used within the Nextcloud snap for doing something similar. Then you make your `library-sample` app call e.g. `library_sample_wrapper` instead of `library_sample`.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer! I'm going to try to implement this before I give the check.

Comment: Did you have success?